# Create custom WebView Cordova Android 5.1.0

Tags: android, cordova, webview, cordovawebview

I need to create 3 custom Cordova `WebView` using Cordova Android 5.1.0. Previously I have succeeded to create custom `WebView` using Cordova Android 2.7 by modifying/overwriting file `platform/android/src/com/hello/helloapp.java`. Below is my previous code:

```
package com.hello.helloapp;

import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

import org.apache.cordova.Config;
import org.apache.cordova.CordovaInterface;
import org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin;
import org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebView;
import org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebViewClient;

import com.hello.helloapp.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.provider.Settings.SettingNotFoundException;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.JavascriptInterface;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;


public class HelloApp extends Activity implements CordovaInterface {
    int SCREEN_WIDTH;
    int SCREEN_HEIGHT;
    static String parentUrl;;
    CordovaWebView view2;
    CordovaWebView view1;
    CordovaWebView view3;
    static String htmlStr;
    LinearLayout layout;
    boolean connectionStatus;
    private final ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        try {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            Config.init(this);
            this.getScreenSize();
            view1 = (CordovaWebView) findViewById(R.id.local_web_view);
            view1.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
            view2 = (CordovaWebView) findViewById(R.id.external_web_view);
            view2.loadUrl("http://google.com");
            view2.requestFocus(WebView.FOCUS_DOWN);
            view2.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient(this, view2));
            view3 = (CordovaWebView) findViewById(R.id.articles_web_view);
            view3.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/articles.html");
            view2.addJavascriptInterface(this, "GetHTML");
            layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
            if (!isTabletDevice(this)) {
                super.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
            }
            if (isAirplaneModeOn(this)) {
                connectionStatus = false;
            } else if (isNetworkOnline()) {
                connectionStatus = true;
            } else
                connectionStatus = false;
            System.out.println(connectionStatus);
            if (!connectionStatus) {
                view2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                view3.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/articles.html");
                view3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public boolean isNetworkOnline() {
        boolean status = false;
        try {
            ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getNetworkInfo(0);
            NetworkInfo netInfo1 = cm.getNetworkInfo(1);

            if ((netInfo != null && netInfo.getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED)
                    || (netInfo1 != null && netInfo1.getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED)) {
                status = true;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
        System.out.println(status);
        return status;

    }

    public static boolean isTabletDevice(Context activityContext) {
        // Verifies if the Generalized Size of the device is XLARGE to be
        // considered a Tablet
        boolean xlarge = ((activityContext.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_XLARGE);

        // If XLarge, checks if the Generalized Density is at least MDPI
        // (160dpi)
        if (xlarge) {
            DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
            Activity activity = (Activity) activityContext;
            activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

            // MDPI=160, DEFAULT=160, DENSITY_HIGH=240, DENSITY_MEDIUM=160,
            // DENSITY_TV=213, DENSITY_XHIGH=320
            if (metrics.densityDpi == DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT
                    || metrics.densityDpi == DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH
                    || metrics.densityDpi == DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM
                    || metrics.densityDpi == DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_TV
                    || metrics.densityDpi == DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XHIGH) {

                // Yes, this is a tablet!
                return true;
            }
        }

        // No, this is not a tablet!
        return false;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private static boolean isAirplaneModeOn(Context context)
            throws SettingNotFoundException {

        return Settings.System.getInt(context.getContentResolver(),
                Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, 0) != 0;

    }

    @Override
    public Activity getActivity() {
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public ExecutorService getThreadPool() {
        return threadPool;
    }

    public void getScreenSize() {
        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        SCREEN_WIDTH = display.getWidth();
        SCREEN_HEIGHT = display.getHeight();

    }

    public class MyWebViewClient extends CordovaWebViewClient {

        private CordovaInterface cordova;

        public MyWebViewClient(CordovaInterface ctx, CordovaWebView app) {
            super(ctx, app);
            this.cordova = ctx;
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView arg0, int arg1, String arg2,
                String arg3) {
            arg0.loadUrl("javascript:navigator.notification.alert(\"Sorry,the network is not available.\",\"null\");");

        }

        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(final WebView view, String url) {

            connectionStatus = isNetworkOnline();
            System.out.println(connectionStatus);
            if (connectionStatus) {
                System.out.println("---------shouldoverride-------" + url);
                if (url.contains(".pdf")&& !url.contains("originUrl")) {
                    System.out.println(HelloApp.htmlStr);
                            view1.loadUrl("javascript:downloadFile(\"" + url + "\",\""
                            + HelloApp.htmlStr + "\",\"" + HelloApp.parentUrl
                            + "\");");
                    return false;
                } else if (url.contains("search?")
                        && HelloApp.parentUrl
                                .equalsIgnoreCase("http://google.com/")) {
                    System.out.println("parenturl");
                    url = url.concat("&showAll=false");
                    view2.loadUrl(url);
                    return false;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            } else {
                view1.loadUrl("javascript:navigator.notification.alert(\"Sorry,the network is not available.\",\"null\");");
                return true;
            }
        }

        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            if (url.contains(".pdf")) {

            }else {
                HelloApp.parentUrl = url;
                if (view2.canGoBack() && view2.canGoForward()) {
                    view1.loadUrl("javascript:callBackFun(\"F_1B_1\")");
                } else if (view2.canGoForward()) {
                    view1.loadUrl("javascript:callBackFun(\"F_1\")");
                } else if (view2.canGoBack()) {
                    view1.loadUrl("javascript:callBackFun(\"B_1\")");
                }
            }
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        }

        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

            super.onPageFinished(view, url);

            if (url.contains(".pdf")) {

            } else {
                System.out.println("----------------" + url);
                view2.loadUrl("javascript: GetHTML.getHtml(document.body.innerHTML);");
                view2.loadUrl("javascript: $(\".content-pricing\").hide()");
                 view2.loadUrl("javascript: $(\"a[href*='mailto']\").removeAttr('href');");

                 System.out.println("REMOVE------------------------>>>");
                 view2.loadUrl("javascript:$('head').append('<style>#coverImageUrl, .content-pricing, .price-disclaimer {display : none;}</style>')");

                layout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        }
    }

    public Object onMessage(String arg0, Object arg1) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void setActivityResultCallback(CordovaPlugin arg0) {

    }

    @Override
    public void startActivityForResult(CordovaPlugin arg0, Intent arg1, int arg2) {

    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public void getHtml(String html) {
        this.htmlStr = html.replace("\"", "\'").replaceAll("\n", "").replaceAll("%22", "\'").trim();
    }

}
```

Now there is lots of update in Cordova, they also update there `CordovaWebView` code. After updating Cordova Android version from 2.7 to 5.1.0, app is crashed. I tried to use `SystemWebView` instead of `CordovaWebView` but still get error and crashes as some of methods are missing in `SystemWebView`.

Please help how can I update previous `WebView` code or create new multiple `WebView` in Cordova 5.1.0.

Thanks!!

Comment: You have to use SystemWebView. Which methods are missing in SystemWebView? Update your code with SystemWebView, tell me what crash and I'll try to help you

Answer (score 0):

This is how I implemented new Cordova library in my existing project.

```
public class MyWebViewFragment extends Fragment{
                private Activity mActivity;
                private SystemWebView syswvPhoneWebview;
                private CordovaWebView wvPhoneWebview;

                @Override
                public void onAttach(Context context) {
                    super.onAttach(context);
                    mActivity = (Activity) context;

                }

                @Override
                public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    if (mView == null) {
                        mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_web_view, null);
                        setLayoutViews(mView);

                    }
                    return mView;
                }

                private void setLayoutViews(View mView) {

                  syswvPhoneWebview = (SystemWebView) mView.findViewById(R.id.wvPhoneWebview);
                    wvPhoneWebview = new CordovaWebViewImpl(new SystemWebViewEngine(syswvPhoneWebview));

                    wvPhoneWebview.init((CordovaInterface) getParentFragment(), parser.getPluginEntries(), parser.getPreferences());

                    syswvPhoneWebview.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);
                    syswvPhoneWebview.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
                    syswvPhoneWebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                    syswvPhoneWebview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
                    syswvPhoneWebview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
                    syswvPhoneWebview.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);

        wvPhoneWebview.loadUrl("www.google.com");
                    SystemWebViewEngine systemWebViewEngine = (SystemWebViewEngine) wvPhoneWebview.getEngine();
                    syswvPhoneWebview.setWebViewClient(new DocumentViewClient(systemWebViewEngine, mActivity));
            }
            }
```

now webviewclient code.

```
public class DocumentViewClient extends SystemWebViewClient {

       private final Activity activity;


    public DocumentViewClient(SystemWebViewEngine parentEngine, Activity activity) {
        super(parentEngine);
        this.activity = activity;

    }
}
```